# Getting unwanted spaces in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the following python code for playing around with files

```
from sys import argv
script , fn = argv
print "We shall play with files\n"
print "You chose the file '%s'\n" %fn
print"We shall now play with the file\n"
x = open(fn,'w+')
print "Let's write something into the file\n"
y = raw_input("What do you want to be written into the file?\n")
x.write(y)
print"Here's what you wrote into the file\n"
z = x.read()
print z
```

Now the problem is, when I run the file and enter the string value for y, python does not show any error but in the output, nothing is printed after the Here's what you wrote into the file except for lots of spaces and new lines. When I open the text file, the string is present but a lot of [NULL] characters are also present. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: `x.read()` here isn't working because after you write to the file, the file seek is at the end. You could do `x.seek(0)` to reset it. Without knowing what you put into the raw_input, it's tough to know why you're seeing ascii characters in the file itself.

Comment: General tip: use more suggestive variable names than x, y and z. infile and line might be good ones. This makes it not only easier to read the code, but also easier to read the whole question (like references to variables in surrounding text).